Recommend Delete vs Delete After a Review
After I recommend deleting a question or answer during a review I've noticed when looking at the History it will say "Recommend Deletion" after my name. I've also noticed that sometimes it will just say "Delete" after other names. Is there a difference between "Delete" and "Recommend Deletion" and what determines which will be displayed?

Voting to delete is a privilege you are yet to earn (they are unlocked at 10k and 20k reputation). Those who have the privilege can vote to delete, those that don't can only recommend its deletion. Also, as Zoe comments, if a user has run out of delete votes, then they will (likely) show as recommending deletion.

Also, IIRC, 20k users who run out of delvotes revert to "recommend deletion"

And if an answer is positively scored, delete votes in review are recommendations.

Recommending deletion is a substitute for casting real delete votes, for cases where the reviewer is ineligible to cast a delete vote on the post, because either:

The user has insufficient reputation to cast real delete votes. (Recommend) delete reviews are only possible on answers, so you need 20K reputation to cast delete votes from review. Users with less reputation will leave recommend delete reviews instead.
The user has already cast the maximum number of real delete votes they are allowed in a day.
The post has a positive score.

On Stack Overflow 4 recommend delete (6 on most sites) votes complete a review, instead of 3 real delete votes. In which case, if the post has 0 or negative score, the post will be 'deleted via review' rather than just 'deleted.' This will allow the post author to single-handedly undelete their answer at the cost of raising an automatic moderator flag. Posts deleted by real delete votes will need additional undelete votes from other users, and cannot be single-handedly reinstated by their author.
If the post has a positive score, a completed recommend deletion review will simply raise an automatic flag for moderators, and mark any existing VLQ/NAA flags as helpful, which in the case of VLQ, will incur an automated downvote from the system.
